# Aligning Information in PHP/HTML

Tags: html, css

I have this code which currently displays the information like this:

```
 <?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","example","password") or die("Could not connect to localhost");
mysql_select_db("exampledb") or die( "Could not connect to database");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tablexample");

echo "<b>" . "Name"  . "</b>" . "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" . "<b>" . "Number" . "</b>";
echo "<br/>";
echo "<br/>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
echo  ucwords($row['name']) . "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" . ucwords($row['number']) . "<br>"; 
echo "<hr width='20%'>";
  }
?>


Name              Number

B              (888) 888-3545
C         (098) 545-4354
Cl               (888) 888-3545
Da              (888) 888-3545
H               (888) 888-3545
H               (888) 888-3545
Khzdf              (888) 888-3545
```

BUT I want them to align like this (it should override how many letters each name has and have the same space:

```
Name              Number

B              (888) 888-3545
C              (098) 545-4354
Cl             (888) 888-3545
Da             (888) 888-3545
H              (888) 888-3545
H              (888) 888-3545
Khzdf          (888) 888-3545
```

-- Would this be done in CSS or PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest way to solve the problem would be this.

In your code you can change this:

```
echo  ucwords($row['name']) . "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" . ucwords($row['number']) . "<br>";
```

to this:

```
echo  "<span style='display:inline-block; width:200px; text-align:left;'>" . ucwords($row['name']) . "</span><span style='display:inline-block; text-align:left;'>" . ucwords($row['number']) . "</span><br>";
```

Note: change `200px` as needed.

Comment: Thank you that looks good except the text is to the very right of the screen. How would I make it so that is in the center of the screen?

NOTE: I have already tried <center>

Comment: You are welcome. It depends on many factors, but the quickest would be this: **echo  "<div style='margin: 0 auto;'><span style='display:inline-block; width:200px; text-align:left;'>" . ucwords($row['name']) . "</span><span style='display:inline-block; text-align:left;'>" . ucwords($row['number']) . "</span></div><br>";**

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered using a table? Tables are great .... for displaying structured data

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column1</th>
            <th>column</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Column1 data</td><td>column 2 data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `<thead>` stands for `table header` it should be used to wrap the header parts of the table :)

Answer (score 0):

> Would this be done in CSS or PHP?

Neither! HTML `<table>` is what you are looking for.. they are also semantic adequate.